# metaWeblog in python xmlrpc

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

The older version of this library `xmlrpclib` had support for `metaWeblog` which mean easy posting for the likes of blogs to places such as *wordpress*. But this appears to have been removed in the latest versions. I enclose which appear to be the available methods for the new library `xmlrpc`

```
['APPLICATION_ERROR', 'Binary', 'Boolean', 'BytesIO', 'DateTime', 'Decimal', 'Error', 'ExpatParser', 'FastMarshaller', 'FastParser', 'FastUnmarshaller', 'Fault', 'GzipDecodedResponse', 'INTERNAL_ERROR', 'INVALID_ENCODING_CHAR', 'INVALID_METHOD_PARAMS', 'INVALID_XMLRPC', 'MAXINT', 'METHOD_NOT_FOUND', 'MININT', 'Marshaller', 'MultiCall', 'MultiCallIterator', 'NOT_WELLFORMED_ERROR', 'PARSE_ERROR', 'ProtocolError', 'ResponseError', 'SERVER_ERROR', 'SYSTEM_ERROR', 'SafeTransport', 'Server', 'ServerProxy', 'TRANSPORT_ERROR', 'Transport', 'UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING', 'Unmarshaller', 'WRAPPERS', '_Method', '_MultiCallMethod', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_binary', '_datetime', '_datetime_type', '_iso8601_format', '_strftime', 'base64', 'boolean', 'datetime', 'dumps', 'errno', 'escape', 'expat', 'getparser', 'gzip', 'gzip_decode', 'gzip_encode', 'http', 'loads', 'sys', 'time', 'urllib']
```

The specification for metaWeblog appears in the following link: https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_MetaWeblog_API and the original code from `xmlrpclib` would look something like this:

```
post_id = xmlrpclib.metaWeblog.newPost(wp_blogid, wp_username, wp_password, data, status_published)
```

and the new version I'd like to try for python3 should be along the lines of:

```
import xmlrpc.client
server = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(wp_url)
post_id = xmlrpc.client.metaWeblog.newPost(wp_blogid, wp_username, wp_password, data, status_published)
```

But there is not method to invoke. Is there an equivalent method to `metaWeblog.newPost`